# drupal zen theme using sass - sub folder dont get regenerated

Tags: theming

i have followed [these instructions](https://drupal.org/node/1548946) to install ruby and compass and sass, everything is ok and works. However, do i need to do a 'compass watch' at a lower level for the component and layout folders in my zen theme folders as well? for example, if i change .../sass/layouts/fixed.scss it doesnt automatically regenerate the equivalent ...css/layouts/fixed.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compass watch` should only need to be run from your subtheme folder.  Files in the components and layout folders should use partials (files beginning with underscore).  Then you have to make sure to use `@import "components/fixed";` inside your `styles.scss` for each partial you want to include.

When compass compiles the `styles.scss` file, the partials that you have `@import`'s for will be automatically included in `style.css`

Comment: i checked the styles.scss file and it already has that in there by default. I notice that when I amend the responsive.scss file (change the page width) , in my terminal session it shows "change detected to layouts/_responsive.scss, overwrite css/styles.css" but it is not doing anything with equivalent layouts/_responsive.css file? The change seems to be applied to styles.css, and it works, but not the way I expected.